# How to use a pointer's methods in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I have a code in which I use a pointer to a class that I made. As an example lets say I have a Person method, and each Person had a name. Now lets say I use a pointer for a person like

```
Person& * person_;
```

Now lets say I'm trying to get the name of the person using the pointer I have. If I do something as simple as

```
person_.getName()
```

It will return an error saying that it's a non-class type.

My question is: if all I have is the pointer to work with, how do I use the methods of the class it's pointing to?

Comment: There is no such thing as a pointer to a reference.

Comment: You cannot have pointers to references. It's hard to reason about how you do stuff with invalid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the pointer notation:

```
person_->getName()
```

`->` is what you want.

Comment: which is merely syntactic sugar for `(*person).getName()`

Answer (score 5):

I don't how you got the compiler to even accept `Person& * person_`, since that's a meaningless declaration (there are no pointers to references). Assuming you actually used `Person* person_`, simply use the `->` operator: `person_->getName()`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `person_->getName();`

Answer (score 1):

`person_->getName()` is shorthand for `(*person_).getName()`.  Both will work.  Also, as @Marcelo pointed out, it should be `Person& * person_;`

Answer (score 0):

`person_->getName()` is what you should be using.

You can read about it [on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/)